# No input file specified. error codeigniter on godaddy

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a installed Codeigniter on godaddy inside a subdirectory, the url is http://westlinebuilders.com/westlinecrm/

the login page opens fine, but when i click on login button or if i access any other controller it shows me No input file specified. i dont have any .htaccess file inside westlinebuilders.com/westlinecrm directory, i tried creating new htaccess file and put it inside westlinecrm directory and followed the instructions on how to fix no file input error using google search, but no luck till now, can anyone please help me on this?

my verifylogin.php controller code is

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access
 allowed');

 class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct()  {    parent::__construct();   
 $this->load->model('user','',TRUE);  }

  function index()  {    //This method will have the credentials
 validation    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');   
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password',
 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)    {
      //Field validation failed.&nbsp; User redirected to login page     $this->load->helper('url');
         $this->load->helper('html');    $this->load->view('templates/header');
      $this->load->view('templates/menu');  
      $this->load->view('client/loginform');     $this->load->view('templates/footer');    }    else    {
      //Go to private area
      redirect('summary', 'refresh');    }

  }

  function check_database($password)  {    //Field validation
 succeeded.&nbsp; Validate against database    $username =
 $this->input->post('email');

    //query the database    $result = $this->user->login($username,
 $password);

    if($result)    {
      $sess_array = array();
      foreach($result as $row)
      {
        $sess_array = array(
          'id' => $row->id,
          'email' => $row->email1
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
      }
      return TRUE;    }    else    {
      $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
      return false;    }  } } ?>
```

Comment: can we see your `verifylogin` controller code?

Comment: And is your main directory also containg a Codeigniter project?

Comment: no, my main directory contains Wordpress Website

Comment: comment out all the code in your index function and just echo somethis and check whether the control is coming there or not

Comment: i have done it, but it shows the same error

Comment: then try to create a sub domain instead of putting the code in sub directory.

Answer (score 7):

I am running the codeignitor in a subdomain in the godaddy. I tried all the solutions above. But it doesn't work. For me the `RewriteRule` makes the problem.

`RewriteRule` which makes problem

```
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ [L]
```

Corrected `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

So the working `.htaccess` code is below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The option `[QSA,L]` worked for me on Godaddy server with CI 3.

Comment: This worked for me as well on Godaddy server, Php 5.6.27 with CI 3

Answer (score 1):

I have made it work by using the following `.htaccess` rule

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /crm/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ [L]
</IfModule>
```

and i have created a sub domain, renamed all model files first character to lowercase, now its working

Answer (score 1):

Overwrite the content of your .htaccess file in the root folder of your project with this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

This would fix it. Most times it is the csrf that causes it. I believe you set it to TRUE in your config file.

Let me know if its working now.

Answer (score -1):

http://westlinebuilders.com/westlinecrm/index.php/verifylogin

your url parsing method wrong.try to use

http://westlinebuilders.com/westlinecrm/verifylogin

why don't u use simple .htaccess code ...

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /westlinecrm/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Another issue on your code..Applying comment was wrong

```
  function index()  {    //This method will have the credentials
   validation    $this->load->library('form_validation');
```

correct way

```
   function index()  {    //This method will have the credentials
   validation    
   $this->load->library('form_validation');
```

Comment: his url is correct unless he has not removed index.php through .htaccess

Comment: function index()  {    //This method will have the credentials
 validation    $this->load->library('form_validation');

check this code again

Comment: i have created .htaccess file inside westlinecrm directory, and it gives me 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: i have also create sub domain http://crm.westlinebuilders.com still same problem, any help guys?